# How to convert data type from varchar to number in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I want to convert a field currently in varchar data type to number data type in the Views of SQL Server say `(dbo.CUSTOMER.STORE_NBR)` from Varchar to number.
How to do that ?
Will `CONVERT` function will do the necessity?
If yes, can you help us with syntax?

Comment: You Can use cast function for data type conversions.You can go through the following msdn manual. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In Sql Server 2012 and up: each of these will return `null` when the conversion fails instead of an error.

- [**`try_convert(datatype,val)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx)
- [**`try_cast(val as datatype)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh974669.aspx)
- [**`try_parse(val as datatype [using culture])`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126.aspx)

So if you want to change the way a view is returning the value you would use something like:

```
alter view dbo.myView as 
  select
    ....
    , store_nbr = try_cast(dbo.customer.store_nbr as int)
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cast an existing column from varchar to int, you have to change the definition of this column, using [alter table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx)

For instance :

```
alter table my_table alter column my_column int null
```

If you don't want to change your table structure, and just want to cast in a select, [cast and convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) would do the job

For instance :

```
select cast(my_column as int)
from my_table
```

Comment: Hi @irimias i don't want to alter table, i want to change the data type in the Package view level in Sql server.
Yes CONVERT function is what i want .Can you please tell me how to use this for my field?
Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: @Siddhartha: if the answer is not relevant, can you please update your question and describe a bit more your issue and what you want to do exactly? ("Package view level"??)